# Spring Boot with Thymeleaf: Is there a Way to refresh page automaticly for different User? (Or send Data from Endpoint to Endpoint)

Tags: java, html, spring-boot, networking, thymeleaf

I am coding a little Chess game and if i move a piece i want it to change on all Users Websites which it does but only after refreshing the page. How do i automatically refresh or send the Move directly to different Users?

```
package com.example.handandbrainchess;

import com.example.handandbrainchess.Service.ApplicationService;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

@Controller
public class WebController {

    private final ApplicationService service;
    private Integer moveRow1;
    private Integer moveRow2;
    private Integer moveColumn1;
    private Integer moveColumn2;
    public WebController(ApplicationService service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String index(Model m){
        m.addAttribute("Feld",service.getFeld());
        return "start";
    }
    @GetMapping("/move")
    public String move(Model m, @RequestParam("idrow") int idrow, @RequestParam("idcolumn") int idcolumn){
      //  System.out.println("Reihe: " + idrow + " Spalte: "+ idcolumn);
      //  m.addAttribute("Feld",service.getFeld());
        if(moveRow1 == null){
            moveRow1 = idrow;
        }
        else if(moveRow2 == null){
            moveRow2 = idrow;
        }
        if(moveColumn1 == null){
            moveColumn1 = idcolumn;
        }else if(moveColumn2 == null){
            moveColumn2 = idcolumn;
        }
        if(moveRow2 != null && moveColumn2 != null){
            service.move(moveRow1,moveColumn1,moveRow2,moveColumn2); //after this refresh
            moveRow1 = null;
            moveRow2 = null;
            moveColumn1 = null;
            moveColumn2= null;
        }
        return "redirect:/";
    }

    @PostMapping("/")
    public String init(){
        service.init();
        return "redirect:/";
    }
}
```

This is currently my Controller and after /move when service.move gets called i want it to refresh.

Its my first Project with Spring Boot and HttpServelt in general.
So i dont really know what i can try to do.

Comment: Take a look at [WebSockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API) for one possible option. Spring has support for WebSockets (you can search for various tutorials).

Comment: I have added a Websocket and now i can send the moves played trough the console to the other player but im not quite sure how i use this to set the field. I dont know how i can access the move method for example.

Comment: You can ask a new, specific question describing this new, specific problem (with a new [mre]).